# Get word from last executed bash command

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script with something like this:

```
git clone ssh://anothersite.com /home/user/another_directory
```

I need to check if the command has worked, and only then proceed to the next commands. I solved it in a similar way:

```
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
echo "{$2} command failed.";
exit 1
```

I need the word "clone" or another word that will be encountered further in the script instead of {$ 2}. If I substitute $ 0, then it gives me the name of the script that I ran, and not the command "git clone" as I expect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to check if the command has worked

Check with an `if`.

```
if ! git clone ssh://anothersite.com /home/user/another_directory; then
   echo "Clone failed" >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

> I need the word "clone" or another word that will be encountered further in the script instead of {$ 2}

Write a handy wrapper function and pass command to execute as arguments.

```
failon() {
    if ! "$@"; do
       echo "Command failed: $*" >&2
       exit 1
    fi
}
failon git clone ssh://anothersite.com /home/user/another_directory
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use shell functions to achieve that. Here is an example implementation with the function `my_git_function` that will display an error message:

```sh
# Process git operation
# Parameters : my_git_function [ git_operation [ operation_arguments ] ]
# Return : git exit status code, 0 if NOP or success
my_git_function() {
  if [ $# = 0 ]; then
    return 0
  fi
  local git_operation="$1"
  shift
  if git "$git_operation" "$@"; then
    return 0
  else
    local exit_code="$?"
    echo "Command $git_operation failed with exit code $exit_code." >&2
    return "$exit_code"
  fi
}
# Example with clone
if ! my_git_function clone ssh://anothersite.com /home/user/another_directory
  # Failed command, error message already displayed
fi
```

Comment: Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net . Do not use `$*` - do `"$@"`. Do not  use `[ $? ...`. do `if ! my_git_function ....`. Prefer lower case variables in your scripts.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for the feedback. I'll edit accordingly. For the lowercase variables in script, its mainly to avoid collisions with existing environment variables, so i guess it's ok with a LOCAL prefix ?

Comment: If you declare the variables with `local` then they are truly local and don't need a prefix.

Comment: @John Kugelman Noted, i'm aware of `local`. As an old dude, i tend to keep to POSIX. As it is a bash question, i should have take it.